# Looking for a command line tool to celebrate programming success

Tags: gratis, linux, command-line

It's always a great joy to see your complicated program finally compiling and running succesfully after hundreds of thousands of errors and warnings hour after hour.

What I'm looking for is software that runs in the terminal I can use to share my joy with my classmates. Something along the lines of terminal fireworks/explosions, silly animations.

It must run on Linux, and definitely should be free.

Comment: Check out `cMatrix`

Answer (score 5):

[Cowsay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowsay) is a classic, although it's a lot more tame than fireworks — it isn't even animated. You could take it up a notch with [Ponysay](http://erkin.co/ponysay/).

On the animation side, [asciiquarium](http://www.robobunny.com/projects/asciiquarium/html/), which uses the [Term::Animation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-Term-Animation/) Perl module. Unfortunately, I can't find much *else* made with that.

I also discovered that the [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) framework comes with a number of demo programs, including **firework**. It's not the most beautiful, but you could also adapt it to be more dramatic without much work. Perhaps also because it's not that great, the Linux distro I'm on doesn't build and package the demos, but it's really easy to download [the source](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/), untar, then change to the test directory and do the standard `./configure; make`. (You probably already have ncurses on your system and so don't need to build the whole thing.)

You could also use `worm` from the same demo collection. I find it oddly mesmerizing.